# How to Sending Data to controller with serialize and other variable in yii?

Tags: jquery, yii

I have function below which I want send to controller using ajax. I'm using code like this `'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize() + '&idcab2= ' + idcabok + ' '  ",` but the `$(this).serialize()` not send to controller but the variable idcab2 has success send to controller. Any one can help me, why serialize data not send to controller?

This it my complete code:

```
function editCabang(idcab)
{
  var idcabok=idcab;
  echo CHtml::ajax(array(
           'url'=>array('Tbcabang/update'), 
           'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize() + '&idcab2= ' + idcabok + ' '  ",
           'type'=>'POST',
            'dataType'=>'json',
            'success'=>"function(data)
            {
                if (data.status == 'failure')
                {
                    $('#dialogClassroom div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                          // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                    $('#dialogClassroom div.divForForm form').submit(editCabang);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#dialogClassroom div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                    setTimeout(\"$('#dialogClassroom').dialog('close') \",3000);
                }

            } ",
            ))
```

Comment: Could you please try `$(this).serialize()` without idcab2 and get e dump in your action. CVarDumper::dump($_POST)

Comment: but i need send variable idcab2 to controller

Answer (score 0):

Serialise the form instead of self

```
var form = $('#my_form');
'data'=> "js:$(form).serialize() + '&idcab2= ' + idcabok + ' '  ",
```

In addition, I don't know what your controller is expecting, but I'll consider adding to the form variables rather than appending a string.

```
$(form).serialize() + {idcab2: idcab2}
```

If you want to use the format you had above to add the additional variables, you could post it to the URL

```
  'url'=>url + '&idcab2= ' + idcabok , 
  'data'=> "js:$(form).serialize() + '&idcab2= ' + idcabok + ' '  ",
```